# How do I hide Menu whose children are hidden?

Tags: eclipse, menu, eclipse-luna, e4

I have some menus on Main Menu in Eclipse 4 Application Project whose children are contributed with the help of fragments from different plugins. I have applied permissions on sub-menus according to logged in user. 
My problem is even after no sub-menu of a menu has the permission and none of them is visible but still menu is visible. I want to hide that menu. Any Suggestions.

Update: My class for model Processor and plugin.xml

```java
public class MenuProcessor {
  public MenuProcessor(){}
  @Execute
  public void execute(@Named("application_luna.menu.contract(fo)") MMenu menu)
  {
     if(menu.getChildren().isEmpty())
         menu.setVisible(false);
  }
}
```

```xml
 <extension
     id="com.swte.approval.ui.fragment"
     point="org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model">
  <fragment
        uri="fragment.e4xmi">
  </fragment>
  <processor
        apply="always"
        beforefragment="false"
        class="com.swte.approval.ui.MenuProcessor1">
  <element
    id="application_luna.menu.contract(fo)">
    </element>
 </processor>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a [processor](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/26/processors-e4-model/) on the menu.

You declare the processor in the plugin.xml as part of the 'org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model' extension point.

```xml
<extension
     id="playerFragment"
     point="org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model">
  ... other elmeents
  <processor
        beforefragment="false"
        class="package.MenuProcessor">
     <element
           id="menu.id">
     </element>
  </processor>
</extension>
```

The declaration names the class to run and the model element that it applies to.

The processor code could then inject the named menu and make it invisible if there are no children. Something like (not tested):

```java
public class MenuProcessor
{
  @Inject @Named("menu.id")
  private MMenu menu;

  @Execute
  public void execute()
  {
    if (menu.getChildren().isEmpty())
      menu.setVisible(false);
  }
```

Note: you must inject the menu element as a field in the class, specifying it as a parameter on the `execute` method will not work. This is because the element is only available for injection when the class is constructed.

Comment: Sir, I am getting following message: Unable to process "MenuProcessor.menu": no actual value was found for the argument "MMenu[@javax.inject.Named(value=application_luna.menu.contract(fo))]" where MenuProcessor is the class of processor

Comment: Well, I took care of Exception but I think that model processor is never executed. I tried printing something. Any suggestions.

Comment: Works fine testing here. You will have to show us your code.

Comment: Well, the constructor is triggered but not the execute method.

Comment: You must inject the menu as a field in the class as I showed, not as a parameter on the `execute` method. The menu is only available for injection when the class is constructed.

Comment: Well, I have tried injecting Menu in 3 ways, but the problem is it returns null. Even when I search for main menu with MWindow.getMainMenu(), it returns null. Any Suggestions

Comment: If you are injecting as a class field it cannot be null, instead you get an exception if the id can't be found. Are you using the correct id for the menu as specified in the Application.e4xmi?

Comment: I am getting Null Pointer exception on the method: MWindow.getmainMenu() and even on menu.getChildren(). Would u like the see the Stacktrace